# Is it possible to run a Vim clientserver instance over SSH+tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

I've been a vim junkie for a year or so now and I've got some great little tricks burnt in to my memory. I do a lot of development (at the office) in a terminal on Ubuntu.

One of the things I value most is having tmux taking care of my sessions so that if Gnome, or anything else, decides to kirk out then I haven't lost a thing.

Additionally, I run a vim clientserver (C-b :neww 'vim --servername d') as one of my tmux windows and use it to receive any files I want to work with while I have my other tmux windows doing various jobs. It means I can have one vim open with no confusion about what I'm editing.

When I'm working remotely (via SSH,) I connect to my tmux session and carry on but I have one problem: vim won't start a client-server instance.

I presume it is X related but I can't seem to find the difference between a local tmux and a tmux via ssh.

Comment: The expression "kirk out" gives me the impression that your window manager has the habit of abruptly heading off to risa with green-skinned ladies.

Comment: @intuited cf. http://www.applegeeks.com/comic_archive/viewcomic.php?issue=135

Comment: Oh, okay.  I was also thinking that it might ———— start, and ———— stop, so ———— frequentlythatyoucan't! get! anything! ———— done!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it uses X properties to communicate. Try running your remote SSH session with the -X option to allow X11 forwarding. You may also have to enable that feature on the server side. You may also have to manually adjust the DISPLAY environment variable (to "localhost:10.0") since the existing session will already have your local one from when it started.

Comment: Interesting design decision. Does not to seem to work with Putty from Windows despite https://superuser.com/questions/119792/how-to-use-x11-forwarding-with-putty :-(

Answer (score 3):

This really is more appropriate as a comment to @keith but I wanted to elaborate a little:

His answer solved it perfectly with a simple -X when connecting but I took it that one step further by adding to my `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host mydevserver.example.com
ForwardX11 yes
```

---

Additionally, I was tempted to investigate repeating this for a headless development server that's located off-site that I'm regularly working on.

1. I installed the most basic X11 components with yum: yum group install 'X11 Desktop Environment'
2. Created an alias in my zsh aliases file to start X on demand (performance still matters on a dev machine!)
   `alias initFakeDisplay=startx -- /usr/bin/Xvfb :2 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &`

Then in future, I can connect with X11 forwarding enabled and use the same tmux+vim technique to run a vim clientserver

Comment: I am trying to get a headless dev machine working how you are talking about. However even after i start the flex display calls to vim --remote* commands say there is no display. Any ideas?